# jQuery radio button change when unchecked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to toggle a radio button with Rails & jQuery. Works great with checkboxes but not with radio buttons.

Basically it does not refresh if billable is unchecked

```
<%= f.radio_button :billable, 'true', :checked => true, :id => 'billable' %> This is a Billable Project <br />
<%= f.radio_button :billable, 'false' %> This is an Internal Project

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billable").change(function() { 
      $("#billing").toggle();
    } );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the generated html code of these two buttons ?

Comment: @timaschew <input checked="checked" id="billable" name="project[billable]" type="radio" value="true" /> This is a Billable Project <br /> 
      <input id="project_billable_false" name="project[billable]" type="radio" value="false" /> This is an Internal Project

Comment: Okay, then the answer of AlienWebguy should be right, isn't it? In your snippet you try to toggle the radio buttion itself. When you do so, both radio buttons will be hidden. What you want to toggle exactly?

Answer (score 1):

by setting :checked => true its forced to always be true

for correctly setting the default value in controller

```
def new
  @event = Event.new(:billable => true)
end
```

then in view

```
<%= f.radio_button :billable, 'true' %> This is a Billable Project <br />
<%= f.radio_button :billable, 'false' %> This is an Internal Project
```

Comment: if you're trying to show hide areas using a radiobutton see [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669525/show-hide-persistence-when-editing-form-where-radio-button-is-used-to-show-hide)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=billable]").change(function() { 
      $("#billing").toggle();
    } );
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/KJ9kE/

Comment: I tried your code but not working either. Here is what's generated. I have tried to replace "input[name=billable]" by input[name=project[billable]] <input checked="checked" id="billable" name="project[billable]" type="radio" value="true" /> This is a Billable Project <br /> 
<input id="project_billable_false" name="project[billable]" type="radio" value="false" /> This is an Internal Project

Comment: Just add quotes to your selector: `$("input[name='project[billable]']")`  --  http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/KJ9kE/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
 var whichChecked = "";
 $('.radio').on('change', function() {

// if radio is checked, decrement variable associated with radio's value
if($(this).is(':checked')) {        
    if ($(this).val() === "int1") {
        int1--;
    }
    if ($(this).val() === "int2") {
        int2--;
    }
    if ($(this).val() === "int3") {
        int3--;
    }
    if ($(this).val() === "int4") {
        int4--;
    }       

    whichChecked = $(this).val();
}
// when unchecked, increment variable associated with radio's value, doesn't work!

if (whichChecked === "int1") {
    int1++;
}
if (whichChecked === "int2") {
    int2++;
}
if (whichChecked === "int3") {
    int3++;
}
if (whichChecked === "int4") {
    int4--;
} 

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#billable").click(function() { 
      $("#billing").toggle(this.checked);
    } );
  });
```

Comment: Your code won't work. It will always show the `#billing` but will never hide it. You have a click listener on the `#billable` radio button. Whenever you click a radio button you always 'check' it, so `this.checked` will always evaluate to true.