# Show/Hide persistence when editing form where radio button is used to show/hide forms element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, refactoring

This code is working but there must be a better way to do this in the Jquery script.

Here's my radio button

```
<%= f.radio_button :losstype, "Cash", :id => 'lc' %>Cash
<%= f.radio_button :losstype, "Asset",:id => 'rb' %>Asset 
<%= f.radio_button :losstype, "Supplies", :id => 'ab' %>Supplies
```

And heres my hidden bit right now.

```
<% if @assetloss.losstype == "Asset"   %>
 <div id="asset_list" style="display: show;">
<% else %>
 <div id="asset_list" style="display: none;">
<% end >
A drop down list to be shown
</div>
```

And the Jquery part

```
$j(document).ready(function(){ 
    $j("input[id='lc']").change(function() {  
    $j("#asset_list").hide();  
  } );
$j("input[id='rb']").change(function() {  
  $j("#asset_list").show("slide");  
} ); 
    $j("input[id='ab']").change(function() {  
  $j("#asset_list").hide(); 
} );
} );
```

Rendered Markup on checked radio button

```
<input checked="checked" id="rb" name="asset_loss[loss_type]" type="radio" value="Asset"/>
```

While it works, I'm sure there's a better way to do this, so I would be asking for refactoring help I guess.

Many Thanks in advance

Ed1. I have realized this is a Jquery Question and need it to check that if "input[id='rb']" is checked (from db) then $j("#asset_list").show();  without needing a change listener

Comment: Please post the rendered markup instead of server-side codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would give them all the same name to group them together.

```
$j("input[name='btnGroupName']").change(function() {  
 if($('#rb').is(':checked')) { 
    $j("#asset_list").show("slide");
  }else{
    $j("#asset_list").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to tidy up everything, and state some of the gotchas. heres the final code.

My Radio Button in view.

```
<%= f.radio_button :loss_type, "cash",    :id => 'button_cash',     :class => 'lt'%>Cash 
<%= f.radio_button :loss_type, "asset",   :id => 'button_asset',    :class => 'lt'%>Asset
<%= f.radio_button :loss_type, "supplies",:id => 'button_supplies', :class => 'lt'%>Supplies
```

You CANNOT use :name  for this, the radio button group name is created using Rails magic and changing that means your data WILL NOT be saved to the db.

The name created is e.g name="asset_loss[loss_type]" which reflects the "model[:field]".  You could use this but Jquery will trip up on this because of the " " which does not encapsulate properly.

e.g

```
$j("input[name="asset_loss[loss_type]"]").change(function() {
```

meaning the blocks are "input[name=" and "]" and doesn't work.

so the final JQuery Code is

```
$j(document).ready(function(){ 
   $j("input[class='lt']").change(function() {  
     if($j('#button_asset').is(':checked')) { 
       $j("#asset_list").show();
     }else if ($j('#button_cash').is(':checked')){
       $j("#cash_type").show();
     }else if($j('#button_supplies').is(':checked')){
       // TODO : Partial for stationery
     }
});
```

And this will work fine.  However back to the main issue of persistence. This JQuery code only does when there is a change.  so when you come back to the page (or reload) it does not read from the db, check what the value is and show/hide fields appropriately.

for this I repeated ALL the JQuery code above but changed

```
$j("input[class='lt']").change(function() {
```

to

```
$j("input[class='lt']").each(function() {
```

now if anyone knows how to string these two together and make it DRY are welcome to comment.
Hope this helps anyone out there trying to do this.